# Should I design a high-power switched mode power supply with surface mount components?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, surface-mount, thermal

I'm designing a SMPS for a fairly high-power application (2kW, 50A).  In looking at the available components, sometimes almost the exact same components are available in surface-mount and through hole versions, for example: FDB035N10A in D2PAK and FDB036N10A in TO-220.  The specs are *very* similar, except the surface-mount component has a higher power dissipation rating.

Is it preferred to use surface mount components in this case?  What is more common or industry-standard?  What are some of the pros and cons?

Comment: This question boils down to "should I design with SM components". It has nothing specifically to do with switchers.

Comment: @Andyaka: Perhaps "should I design with SM for high power" :)  Or even better, "is there any reason *not* to", since the general benefits of SM are well known.

Comment: SMD FETs generally have nicer characteristics, less ringing

Comment: If you believe the data sheets for leaded components then there is no reason to reject them because they are SMD (other than naivety).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use SMD for high power.

The ease of automated assembly is a compelling advantage in most western countries. Here are some things that will help:

- You can get aluminium-backed PCBs that can have SMD power devices on one side, and the aluminium side of the PCB goes flat on a heatsink. The thermal impedence isn't as good as a mica washer but it's workable.
- The lower purchase cost and the much lower assembly cost of power devices means that you can use more of them, which means you can spread the heat.
- Doing something about switching losses is very important because most orthodox current mode PWM has more switching loss than conduction loss when being operated at normal frequencies.
- Generally your SMD PCB will have less parasitic inductance than a thru hole PCB of the same circuit. This will mean cleaner waveforms especially at high currents and can help reduce radiated EMC.
- Some of the better parts are easier to get in SMD.

Answer (score 1):

if the SMD parts support a use with a suitable heatsink there's no reason not to choose them.